# Play podcast from within an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, podcast

Is a tutorial or code example available which embeds a podcast from a URL into an application?

Comment: Although this question was interesting in its time, it is now off-topic - we don't do recommendation questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean playing just a simple audio file there's plenty of tutorials out there. If you're talking about real podcast (which is a xml file that contains references, details and links to audio files) take a look at NSXMLParser and search google for playing audio iphone.